# How to I set the Network Location for an incoming VPN Connection in Windows 8?

Tags: vpn, windows-8, network-location

I'm using Windows 8's Incoming Connections feature to run a PPTP VPN server within my network.

The VPN works perfectly fine, except that remote computers cannot connect to the VPN host itself.

I can ping and connect to all other computers in my local network, but I can't even ping the internal IP address of the VPN host (which is also a file share)

On Windows 7, I solved this issue by setting the network location of the VPN's RAS (Dial In) Interface (on the host machine) to Private.

However, on Windows 8, it defaults to Public, and I can't find any place in the UI to change it. Network locations are now set in the Modern UI Network List, which doesn't show the incoming connection.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Run the following PowerShell commands:

```
$networkListManager = [Activator]::CreateInstance([Type]::GetTypeFromCLSID([Guid]"{DCB00C01-570F-4A9B-8D69-199FDBA5723B}"))
$networkListManager.GetNetworks(3) | Where-Object { $_."GetName".Invoke(@()) -eq "RAS (Dial In) Interface" } | % { $_.SetCategory(1) }
```

The first command creates a NetworkListManager object.
The second command consists of three parts (separated by `|`s):

- The first part lists all registered networks
- The second part filters that list for networks with a specific name.
  (remove the third part to see the results of the filtering)
- The third part sets the network location for all matching networks.  `0` is public; `1` is private.

For more (technical) information, see the [Network List Manager API documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa965312(v=vs.85).aspx).

Answer (score 1):

You can configure this using Local Group Policy Editor as explained in [this Technet discussion](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/2080cab4-fab5-46d6-bde8-c575054c1b2d/assign-nps-vpn-clients-to-private-or-domain-not-public-network?forum=winserverNIS). This answer also applies to Windows 10.

Press Win+R and type GPEdit.msc.

Drill down as follows:

```
Computer Configuration ->
Windows Settings ->
Security Settings ->
Network List Manager Policies ->
"RAS (Dial In) Interface" ->
Network Location
```

Set *Location Type* to `Private`.